# Create a Directory in PhoneGap Application

Tags: cordova, filesystems, directory, ripple

I am using Cordova-2.2.0, Chrome browser, installed Ripple simulator plugin, using Windows 7 OS on my laptop (Not windows 7 OS phone, but Windows 7 OS on my laptop just to be clear).

This is the sample javascript I running to create a folder. But I do not see a folder getting created on my hard drive. But If I package the www folder and use build.phonegap.com to build and install app on my andriod phone I do see it creating folder. This is just sample, but I like Ripple sim and want to use for full testing rather than using Mac X-Code and Android eclipse to debug, this is so much simpler. Can anyone suggest any fix, so that when I run this on my laptop it is still able to create the folder, but when I get ready to deploy package I can leave the code below as is?

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
 }, false);

 function onDeviceReady(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 2000, gotFS, fail);
 }

 function gotFS(fileSystem) 
 {
   fileSystem.root.getDirectory("example", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dir){}
   , function(error){}
   ); 
 }
```

Thanks
Rusty

Comment: Please don't put tag information in the subject line of your question; that's exactly what tags are designed for. The tagging system works extremely well here to bring questions to the attention of people who might be able to answer them. It doesn't need any help. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/blackberry/Ripple-UI/issues/404

I added this piece of code after deviceready

```
   window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
       window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler); 
   }, function(e) {
      console.log('Error', e); 
   });
```